# System Verilog Adapter Interface

Tags: interface, system-verilog

I am using Xilinx's PCIe Core, which in its latest version duplicates the AXI valid signal 22 times.
This means writing something like `{22{1'b1}}` every time I try to drive the valid bit. (http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/50579.html)

I am wondering if I can do some magic, so that I have an interface that has a vector with 22 duplicated bits on the Xilinx PCIe Core side, but just one bit on the side I connect to.

While I can simply assign to a wire which I duplicate in my module I would love to know if I can achieve the same inside the interface.

Is it legal to have modports that do not include all wires of an interface (That way I could have one valid pin for the userside modport and the Vector for the core side)? Can one have assignments in an interface?
Or could I do some `magic` to cause a write to a member in a union to result in updates of other members of the union that do not share bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it legal to have modports that do not include all wires of an interface?

Yes, refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 25.5.4 *Modport expressions*:

> A modport expression allows elements of arrays and structures, concatenations of elements, and assignment pattern expressions of elements declared in an interface to be included in a modport list. This modport expression is explicitly named with a port identifier, visible only through the modport connection.
>   Like explicitly named ports in a module port declaration, port identifiers exist in their own name space for each modport list. When a modport item is just a simple port identifier, that identifier is used as both a reference to an interface item and a port identifier. Once a port identifier has been defined, there shall not be another port definition with this same name.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> interface I;
>   logic [7:0] r;
>   const int x=1;
>   bit R;
>   modport A (output .P(r[3:0]), input .Q(x), R);
>   modport B (output .P(r[7:4]), input .Q(2), R);
> endinterface
> module M ( interface i);
>   initial i.P = i.Q;
> endmodule
> module top;
>   I i1 ();
>   M u1 (i1.A);
>   M u2 (i1.B);
>   initial #1 $display("%b", i1.r); // displays 00100001
> endmodule
> ```

Not all simulators/synthesizer support modeport expressions, so you will have to experiment. Modeport expressions are not new, they are also described in IEEE Std 1800-2005. Maybe the Accellera SystemVerilog 3.1a as well (I'd need to dig up the old LRM to verify).

> Can one have assignments in an interface?

Yes. Synthesis support may be limited for some tools; you'll need to experiment. For simulations, assign statements in an interface can be used to control data for tri-state buses.

```
interface I;
  bit drive_en;
  tri [15:0] io;
  logic [15:0] io_drv;
  assign io = drive_en ? io_drv : 'z;
endinterface
```

Interfaces can also contain their own tasks and functions. If you are using the interface for design, then generally you want to limit keep the interface simple: mostly signals and modports. This is not a rule, just a recommended guideline.

> Or could I do some `magic` to cause a write to a member in a union to result in updates of other members of the union that do not share bits?

More power to you if you got the `magic` to pull it off. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, this allows me to model Xilinx's feed us that bit 22 times as the common sense (? at least to my limited understanding) pass us that 1 bit. Is there such `magic` in the language (does it exist?) if so what would I google for?

Comment: After tinkering with it for a bit I am led to believe that Vivado does not support them, http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/51837.html

Comment: There is no `magic` keyword in the LRM. I formatted it as code to quote it as in the question. If modport expressions are not suppoted, definally try generate (part of Verilog since 2001, IEEE Std 1364-2001). Example: `for(genvar i; i<22;i++) module_name inst_name ( .pin(ifc.bus_pin[i]), .common(ifc.shared_modport) );`

Comment: It can be done easier than that, an `assign` with `{22{localWire}}` should do the trick. Or am I missing somthing? Afterall no modport support means I have to modify the actual code of the module.

Comment: That can work as well. There are multiple ways to handle it, the differences are more are more in architectural intent. I saw modports listed in the interfaces_example.zip description, so I thought it modports was supported, just not modport expressions. Either way it looks like you found a solution. Happy codding.